# Keep CVS folder in EGit commit

Tags: egit

I am experimenting the use Git to manage development environment for one of my client project which is on CVS (and can't move out). Since the environment is quite complicated and has multiple steps to setup, I am hoping version controlling would help. So far it is actually very helpful to do it. However, all the project CVS setting (like the CVS module and branch) are not tracked by git via EGit plugins. so when we recreate the environment we have to reshare the projects that is really inconvenient.

I dig down on the issue and found that EGit does not track CVS folders in those project so the CVS information is lost.

Is there a way to tell EGit to track those folders?

Thanks all.